# Show the last few items on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

How could I keep the just last few items in a `ListView` shown? Currently, I'm using the following line to achieve this.

```
lv.smoothScrollToPosition(lv.getCount());
```

However, `smoothScroll()` is annoying because it has to scroll through all `ListView` elements to get to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ListView.setSelection()` with your preferred position.